# Odoo 9 questions and answer module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm new in odoo 9 and want create module Quiz (question and answer), now I'm create question and anwser https://postimg.org/image/9ys7rfrjp/
(Answer can be True or False).

Now my question is:

How display etc. 10 questions on .xml forms, with radioButon, after user select answer on button submit get resault (5/10 = 5 points) 50%.

Any simple solution?

Comment: Where do you like to place the radio button and what condition

Comment: @VigneshwaranThenraj When create exam (Quiz), question and answer (with radio buttin) can place somewhere on menu or website.